# retrieving array as comma separated values in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using the below code to get the ids from the pr_users table and store it in pr_notification_table,but unable to store the values separated by comma into pr_notifications table. I want to store $notification_data['show_users'] as 1,2,3,4 etc so that notifications are sent to these ids. Its inserting NULL on executing this , I have attached table images also,[image]

pr_notifications table is as below:

[image]

My controller code is:

```html
if($data['rows'][0]['last_status'] == 'Accepted')
   {
    $ids= '22';
   $data['success_message'] = $this->exit_common->send_notification_to_all_roles($ids);
   echo "Success";
   
   }
```

My model code is:

```html
function send_notification_to_all_roles($ids)
  {
   
   global $USER;
   $post_arr = $this->input->post();
    $this->db->select('g.*,id');
  $this->db->from('pr_users as g'); 
   $this->db->where('userroleid', $ids); 
  //$this->db->join($this->myTables['pr_users_details'].' as ud','ud.userid = g.userid');
  //$this->db->join('pr_users_details as ud','ud.userid = g.userids');
  
 /* $this->db->join($this->myTables['users_details'].' as ud','ud.userid = g.userid');
  $this->db->join('pr_resignation_type as gt','gt.id = g.sr_type');*/
  $query=$this->db->get(); 
  
  $return = $query->result_array();
  $arr = explode(',',$return);
  foreach($arr as $num)
  {
   echo $num."<br>";
   }
  print_r($num);
  die;
  
   $manager_id = $this->get_value_by_id('managerid','users',$this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
   $user_id='1';
     $v_memberid = $manager_id . "," . $user_id;
      //$manager_id = $this->get_value_by_id('managerid','users',$this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
     $notification_data['ref_table']   = 'pr_resignation_requests'; 
     $notification_data['ref_id']   = '1';
     $notification_data['modifier_id']  = $USER->id;
     $notification_data['show_users']  = $num;
     $notification_data['notification_descr']= "A new Job has been created" ;//$manager_id;
     $notification_data['notification_text'] = "A new Job has been created";
     $notification_data['added_on']   = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
     $notification_data['url']    = 'exits';
     $notification_data['uurl']    = 'exits';
     $this->db->insert($this->myTables['notifications'],$notification_data);
     return 'Resignation Request submitted successfully';
  }
```

Comment: please check the column datatype and set it as varchar.

Comment: changed to varchar   
its inserting Array Array Array Array

Comment: what is your print_r($num); returns?

Comment: changed code to  $return = $query->result_array();
  $insert = implode(" ",$return);
  print_r($insert);
  die; and its printing Array Array Array Array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to get notification_id from pr_users table, and then use the following code for get notification_id comma seprated.Assume than your notification id array is :- `$user_notification_ids_info`
Now go with this code.

```
$ids = ''; $notification_ids = '';
for($i=0; $i<count($user_notification_ids_info); $i++)
{ 
$ids = $user_notification_ids_info[$i]['notification_id'];
$notification_ids.= $ids.", ";
}
$notification_ids = substr(trim($notification_ids), 0, -1);
```

Now simply `echo $notification_ids;` it will return your comma seprated notification id.
It will helps you try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You want to store $ids comma separated? then use implode().

$arr = array('Hello','World!','Beautiful','Day!');
echo implode(",",$arr);

I hope this will help.

Comment: its inserting Array Array Array Array